# BulkInsert error with RavenDB: Document id must have a non empty value

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb4

I am using the BulkInsert operation of RavenDB 4.0.6 to insert a bunch of products:

```cs
    using (var bulk = Store.BulkInsert())
    {
        foreach (var p in products)
        {
            p.Id = string.Empty; // <-- notice this
            await bulk.StoreAsync(p);
        }
    }
```

Notice that I'm deliberately skipping the identifier creation strategy by explicitly providing `string.Empty` as the value of the Id property. This is based on the RavenDB docs, [section Autogenerated ID's](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/working-with-document-identifiers#autogenerated-ids).

When running the code I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Document id must have a non empty value

Which is directly produced by this codesnippet in [BulkInsertOperation.cs](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/c65eda7a3f666d0b8961899aa0bb2431d51948d2/src/Raven.Client/Documents/BulkInsert/BulkInsertOperation.cs#L384-L387).

My question is **how I can prevent this error** and still keep the same ID-generation strategy as my other code does?

E.g. I never set the Id property to anything other than `string.Empty`. And I'm afraid that setting it to, for example, `Guid.NewGuid.ToString()` might cause other issues (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920628/how-to-loadt-a-ravendb-document-constrained-to-a-collection-when-not-using-d) as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bulk operations, you have to either leave the Id property null (not empty string) to have it auto-generate a sequential ID, or generate a Guid ID manually.

The API is a bit inconsistent between bulk inserts and session inserts:

```
using (var store = new DocumentStore() { Urls = new[] { "http://localhost:8080" } }.Initialize())
{
  using (var bulk = store.BulkInsert("Sample"))
  {
    bulk.Store(new SampleDocument { Name = "Bulk.Store Null Id", Id = null }); // Sequential Id (I.E. SampleDocuments/1-A)
    bulk.Store(new SampleDocument { Name = "Bulk.Store Blank Id", Id = "" }); // Throws Error
    bulk.Store(new SampleDocument { Name = "Bulk.Store Guid Id", Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }); // Guid Id
  }

  using (var session = store.OpenSession("Sample"))
  {
    session.Store(new SampleDocument { Name = "Session.Store Null Id", Id = null }); // Sequential Id (I.E. SampleDocuments/2-A)
    session.Store(new SampleDocument { Name = "Session.Store Empty Id", Id = "" }); // Guid Id
    session.Store(new SampleDocument { Name = "Session.Store Guid Id", Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }); // Guid Id
    session.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I stated indeed. But `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` does seem to have a different side-effect than relying on the `string.Empty`, see also the linked question at the end of my question. Which leads back to my actual question: what can be done to prevent this and keep the same identity strategy?

Comment: I think the core problem is that for Load<T>, type safety only persists for the session. It appears that regardless of the Id strategy, once you close the session, you lose the type safety.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922425/4541880, `store.Query<T>.Where(x => x.Id == id)` should both be performant and type safe, regardless of Id strategy